# Update In Hibernate Association

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, associations, hibernate-mapping

I have hibernate association mapping with one to many relationship as follows :

Visit

|

---> Order

---> Receipt

---> Issue

Visit is one of the entity which has one to mapping with Order,recepit and issues.

There can be a possibility that one visit can have one or many orders, receipts and issues.

At first in ideal scenario visit will be stored and respectively order,receipts and issues will be saved in db.
but what if again for same visit if i want to insert new order ,new receipts and news issues.

In this case i would want that record in visit table must be update as it is same visit instead of insert and record in corrosponding entities must
be inserted as they are new.
How to achive this ??

Hibernate association works fine with first time insert but what if one of the entity in association has be updated only and other to be inserte ???

Comment: It works just fine ... did you try anything before posting the question ?

Comment: @Pras I tried it but every time new Visit Record gets inserted along with Order, receipts, issues where as existing visit should get updated.

Comment: can you post the repository code ? along with entity mappings ?